# onmouseover issues with Safari

Tags: javascript, xhtml, safari, onmouseover, onmouseout

I am trying to get a onmouseover and onmouseout effect in a xhtml page for my navigation menu.

This code only works in Firefox, but nothing else. Can someone please tell me how to get it to work on all browsers?

Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

```
<title>title</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[*/
    function roll_over(img_name, img_src)
    {
        document[img_name].src = img_src;
    }

/* ]]> */
</script>
```

```
                <li><a href="index.html" onmouseover="roll_over('home', 'images/homeSelected.png')" onmouseout="roll_over('home', 'images/home.png')" ><img src="images/home.png" alt="Home" id="home" /></a></li>
              <li><a href="about.html" onmouseover="roll_over('about', 'images/aboutSelected.png')" onmouseout="roll_over('about', 'images/about.png')" ><img src="images/about.png" alt="About Me" id="about" /></a></li>
              <li><a href="portfolio.html" ><img src="images/portfolioSelected.png" alt="My Portfolio" id="portfolio" /></a></li>
              <li><a href="contact.html" onmouseover="roll_over('contact', 'images/contactSelected.png')" onmouseout="roll_over('contact', 'images/contact.png')" ><img src="images/contact.png" alt="Contact Me" id="contact" /></a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried this in chrome and IE 7 & 8 but the error persists. 
Safari gives me the error :TypeError: Result of expression 'document[img_name]' [undefined] is not an object."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try changing your function to look like this:

```
 function roll_over(img_name, img_src) 
    { 
        document.getElementById(img_name).src = img_src; 
    }
```

That way it is directly selecting your `<img>` using your passed id.

Comment: But how do I ID them. Each has a different id. Do I put the same as as ID?

Comment: You already had the ID's setup. In in your img tag you have id=about, id=home etc. So when you were passing onmouseover="roll_over('about','images/about.png)" it is sending the correct ID to the function.

Answer (score 3):

Current releases of Safari will unfortunately ignore the onmouseover. This is because prior to the 6S Apple touch screens (iPhone, iPad) had no equivalent notion of a mouse being over something prior to a press so using mouseover lead to interfaces which did not function as expected on touch screen devices.

So to encourage consistent designs Safari stopped supporting onmouseover even for devices which have a mouse.

Comment: Soo...what are we doing about that if we still want to use hover?